# Get multiple details from distributrion list

Tags: powershell, office365

I'm fairly new to PowerShell but I want to export a number of exchange group details and export those details into a csv file.

Below are the details I want to export:

- Name of group
- DisplayName of group
- PrimarySmtpAddress of group
- RecipientType of group
- Member count of group
- Owners(ManagedBy) of group - Some have multiple owners

For each Owner of the group I also need:
- Owner Name 
- Owner DisplayName
- Owner emailaddress

I've put together the below script but the Csv is completely blank, and not entirely sure where the issue lies.

```
$GroupsCollection=@()

$groups =  Get-Group -ResultSize Unlimited

foreach ($group in $Groups) {
        {

            $GroupInformation = New-Object  -typename PSObject

            Add-Member -InputObject $DLInformation -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DLName -Value ""
            Add-Member -InputObject $DLInformation -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DLDisplayName -Value ""
            Add-Member -InputObject $DLInformation -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DLEmailAddress -Value ""
            Add-Member -InputObject $DLInformation -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DLRecipientType -Value ""
            Add-Member -InputObject $DLInformation -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DLMemberCount -Value ""
            Add-Member -InputObject $DLInformation -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DLOwners -Value ""
            Add-Member -InputObject $DLInformation -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DLOwnerName -Value ""
            Add-Member -InputObject $DLInformation -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DLOwnerDisplayName -Value ""
            Add-Member -InputObject $DLInformation -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DLOwnerEmailAddress -Value ""

           $DLInformation.DLName = $group.Name 
           $DLInformation.DLDisplayName = $group.DisplayName 
           $DLInformation.DLEmailAddress =$group.PrimarySmtpAddress
           $DLInformation.DLRecipientType = $group.RecipientType
           $DLInformation.DLMemberCount = ($group.Members | measure).count
           $GroupInformationOwners = ($group.DisplayName | select -ExpandProperty ManagedBy)
           $DLInformation.DLOwners = $GroupInformationOwners |Out-String
           $DLInformation.DLOwnerName = $GroupInformationOwners.name |out-string
           $DLInformation.DLOwnerDisplayName = $GroupInformationOwners.displayname |out-string
           $DLInformation.DLOwnerEmailAddress = $GroupInformationOwners.PrimarySmtpAddress |out-string
           $GroupsCollection +=  $GroupInformation

        }

}



$GroupsCollection |ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation

$GroupsCollection |Export-Csv -Path "file" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Your script never shows how `$DLInformation` gets created. `Add-Member` is not going to like an input object of `$null`. That should be replaced with `$GroupInformation`.

Comment: Thanks pointing that out! lack of coffee most likely caused me to overlook that bit - I've amended the script but the csv file is still blank after re-running it?

Comment: You also have a second set of `{}`, which effectively creates a script block that is not executed. Those should be removed. Your `$GroupInformationOwners` is not correct either. Check my answer to see if that helps the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help provide a more favorable result.

```
$groups =  Get-Group -ResultSize Unlimited

$GroupsCollection = foreach ($group in $Groups) {

    $GroupInformation = [PSCustomObject]"" | Select-Object DLName,DLDisplayName,DLEmailAddress,DLRecipientType,DLMemberCount,DLOwners,DLOwnerName,DLOwnerDisplayName,DLOwnerEmailAddress
    $GroupInformationOwners = $group.ManagedBy | Foreach-Object { Get-Group $_ }

    $GroupInformation.DLName = $group.Name 
    $GroupInformation.DLDisplayName = $group.DisplayName 
    $GroupInformation.DLEmailAddress = $group.PrimarySmtpAddress
    $GroupInformation.DLRecipientType = $group.RecipientType
    $GroupInformation.DLMemberCount = ($group.Members | measure).count
    $GroupInformation.DLOwners = $group.ManagedBy | Out-String
    $GroupInformation.DLOwnerName = $GroupInformationOwners.name | Out-String
    $GroupInformation.DLOwnerDisplayName = $GroupInformationOwners.displayname | Out-String
    $GroupInformation.DLOwnerEmailAddress = $GroupInformationOwners.PrimarySmtpAddress | Out-String

    $GroupInformation

}
$GroupsCollection |Export-Csv -Path "file" -NoTypeInformation
```

**Explanation:**

I removed all of the `Add-Member` in favor of a more concise instantiation of the `$GroupInformation` object. Your `Add-Member` `-InputObject $DLInformation` value was a null value since `$DLInformation` did not exist at the time those commands were executed. That will throw an error and result in no properties being added to your object.

`$GroupInformationOwners` did not have the correct initial value for you to use it later. Since it only contained the `ManagedBy` collection of strings, you would not have been able to get other Exchange properties from it. Instead, I opted to use `Get-Group` on the `ManagedBy` list items and store that output into `$GroupInformationOwners`. Then the remaining properties could be retrieved as you had previously coded.

We don't need to use `+=` here since you can set can assign a variable the output of a `foreach` loop. `$GroupsCollection` contains the output of the loop because of having `$GroupInformation` solely on a line. `+=` is generally bad practice as a collection grows because it reads one array object, then destroys that array object, and then finally outputs a new array object with more data than the previous object. It is a more inefficient and expensive operation than what we have done here.

Comment: Cheers - We've got CAC up and running and my address isn't whitelisted - yet - so will let you know of the result when I'm back in the office.

Comment: Does ManagedBy contain users or groups? If it is a user, then you should use `get-aduser` instead.

Comment: ManageBy contains users - I've used get-recipient instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for the script, it works exactly how I envisioned mine would haha. Our organisation is huge and the wifi connectivity is probably worse than dial up - so it *only* took about 6 hours to run but it worked in the end. I didn't expect much but you've been really helpful 10/10 from me,cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code.

```
Get-DistributionGroup -ResultSize Unlimited | Foreach{
  $DisplayName=$_.DisplayName 
  $Alias=$_.Alias 
  $EmailAddress=$_.PrimarySmtpAddress 
  $GroupType=$_.GroupType 
  $ManagedBy=$_.ManagedBy
  $Members=Get-DistributionGroupMember -ResultSize Unlimited -Identity $DisplayName 
  $MembersCount=($Members.name).Count 
  $Result=@{'DisplayName'=$DisplayName;'PrimarySmtpAddress'=$EmailAddress;'Alias'=$Alias;'GroupType'=$GroupType;'Manager'=$ManagedBy;$Members;'GroupMembersCount'=$MembersCount}
  $Results= New-Object PSObject -Property $Result  
  $Results | Select-Object DisplayName,PrimarySmtpAddress,Alias,GroupType,Manager,Members,GroupMembersCount| Export-Csv -Path $ExportSummaryCSV -Notype -Append 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing! However many DL's have multiple owners and I need to get the user details of each of the multiple owners - closest I've gotten is the below 'one-liner' which only works with DL's that have only a single owner.  get-group -anr "DL Name" | Select-Object Name,DisplayName,PrimarySmtpAddress,@{n="ManagedBy";e={get-group -anr $_.DisplayName | select -expandproperty ManagedBy}},@{n="ManagedBy User Details";e={get-group -anr $_.DisplayName | select -expandproperty ManagedBy | get-recipient | select Name,DisplayName,PrimarySmtpAddress} | Export-Csv -Path "File" -NoTypeInformation